# Why did the Devas let Brihaspati be their guru even though he had sex with his brothers' wives?

Tags: gods, dharma, sin, guru, brihaspati

Being a guru, Brihaspati had sex with his younger brother's wife and yet why did the devas let him be their guru?

This is is mentioned in Devi Bhagavata Purana [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk01ch11.htm).

Did Brihaspati suffer any consequences because of this act?

The Matsya Purana too tells us [a strange tale](http://kathaasarit.blogspot.com/2013/12/brhaspati-his-loves-and-woes.html) about Brihaspati. According to this story, Brihaspati once met his elder brother Utathya's wife Mamata in solitude. Tempted by her beauty, Brihaspati sought sex with her. And when she refused, he took her by force though she was pregnant at that time.

Comment: The first reference is wrong i.e. "Brihaspati had sex with his younger brother's wife" ; add the correct reference.

Comment: Reference is correct, from the first link: "Târâ is dissatified with Brihaspati since he enjoyed the wife of his younger brother Samvarta."

Comment: I have given an answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56849/24460, you can check it out. @SayNoToCensorship

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto if you are interested, you can also check this out https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56849/24460

Answer (score 3):

The question is:

> Being a guru, Brihaspati had sex with his younger brother's wife and
>   yet why did the devas let him be their guru?

Puranas came into existence, post Mahabharata period.  The main content of each purana will revolve around the main deity.

For example:

Shiva Purana:  Shiva

Bhagavata Purana : Vishnu

Devi Bhagavatam : Devi

---

Apart from the main content, which eulogises respective deity, some interesting anecdotes were also included in those Puranas.

Some of such anecdotes revolved around brihaspati - Guru of Devas.

These anecdotes are more or less related to astrological issues/dharma sastras.

---

In the 1st reference made in the question, it was Chandra, who had affair with Tara, wife of brihaspati and consequential birth of budha.

This story has more related to astrological issue.

Chandra seduced Tara, the wife of Brhaspati and from that union produced Budha. Hence, Budha is  child of Chandra out of illegal affair. Chandra being the father of Budha, ***loves him dearly***. However, Budha is not quite happy about his  origin, and hence, ***hates Chandra the most***.

Thus we see here a love hate relationship.

**[*Astrological explanation*](https://medium.com/thoughts-on-jyotish/the-graha-sambandha-a86d1f283317)**

> Now what happens when Budha occupies the Rasi of Chandra vs. Chandra
>   occupying the Rasi of Budha? When Budha occupies the Rasi of Chandra,
>   Chandra ***supports all activities*** of Budha, while Budha ***troubles the
>   significations of the Chandra’s rasi***.
>
> On the other hand when **Chandra**
>   occupies a Budha’s Rasi, ***it supports*** all the significations of the
>   Bhava connected to that Rasi, where as ***its own significations take a
>   beating*** as Budha does not support it.

---

So don't go by outer meaning of anecdotes of Puranas.  We have to look into inner meaning, some may have relation to something else.

Comment: "Puranas came into existence, post Mahabharata period" -what's the reference for this

Comment: @YDS: It was an inference but not a reference drawn from some text.

Comment: @Srimannarayana The story is real and there is real meaning to it in actual sense. There may be astrological impact but that is only a impact because of the main incident. We can learn different inner meanings from a incident but that does not nullify the actual incident.

Answer (score -4):

Let's look at the story from the Mahābhārata. Bhīṣma narrates this to Satyavatī after he has just told her he cannot break his vow of *brahmacarya* (by performing *[niyoga](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201419.html)* on her daughters-in-law):

> Ādi Parva; Saṃbhava Parva; Ch. 97-98
>
> ...
>
> O queen! In order to prevent Shantanu's lineage from becoming extinct, I will tell you the eternal dharma of Kshatriyas. Hearing this, after consulting priests and those wise ones who know about the dharma that should be followed in time of calamities, determine what is best for the welfare of the world.
>
> Jamadagni's son Rama was angry when his father was killed and in his anger, the immensely illustrious one killed the king of the Haihayas. He sliced off Arjuna's 1000 arms. Then he again took up his bow to conquer the world. Using his wonderful weapons, the great-souled descendant of Bhargava used his arrows to exterminate Kshatriyas from the world twenty-one times. Then Kshatriya women everywhere had offspring through Brahmanas who were self-controlled. The Vedas clearly say that a son so born belongs to the one who accepted the hand. With dharma in their minds, they united with the Brahmanas. The world has thus seen the resurgence of the Kshatriyas.
>
> In earlier times, there was a famous and wise rishi named Utathya. His wife was named Mamata and he loved her dearly. Utathya's younger brother was the immensely energetic Brihaspati, the priest of the gods. He desired Mamata and sought to unite with her. **Mamata told her brother-in-law**, who was most eloquent in speech, '**I am pregnant through your older brother. Therefore, desist.** O illustrious Brihaspati! Utathya's son is in my womb and has studied the Vedas and the Vedangas there. Your semen is infallible and, therefore, this is not possible. **Do not desire me today**.' At these words, the immensely energetic Brihaspati could not suppress his desire, though he had achieved self-control. The desiring one united with her, though she did not desire him in return. When he spilt his semen, the embryo inside the womb said, 'O father! There is no room inside for two of us. I was here first and you have unnecessarily wasted your semen.' At this, the illustrious rishi Brihaspati was angry and cursed Utathya's son, who was in the womb. 'You have spoken at a time that all beings crave for. Therefore, you will enter a long period of darkness.' From this curse was born the rishi Dirghatama. He was Brihaspati's equal in great deeds and great energy. To extend Utathya's lineage, the famous rishi had sons like Goutama and others, all immensely famous.
>
> But Goutama and the other sons were overcome by greed and delusion. They tied him to wood and threw him into the waters of the Ganga. 'This man is blind and old. Why should we support him?' Thinking in this way, the cruel ones returned home...
>
> (Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 1, pp. 274-276)

Note that Mamatā only says, *I am pregnant through your older brother. Therefore, desist...Do not desire me **today***; she doesn't quote from dharma śāstras e.g., [Manusmṛti 9.57-58](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201418.html) which prohibit either brother from approaching the other's wife during normal times. This means rules like these based on which we are now judging Bṛhaspati came much later.

> **The wife of the elder brother is, for the younger, a 'wife of the preceptor'**; and the wife of the younger brother has been declared to be a 'daughter-in-law' for the elder.—(9.57)
>
> If the elder brother has recourse to the wife of the younger, or the younger brother to the wife of the elder, **they become outcasts**, even though 'authorised,'—except in times of distress.—(9.58)
>
> On failure of issue, the woman, on being authorised, may obtain, in the proper manner, the desired offspring, either from her younger brother-in-law or from a ‘Sapiṇḍa’.—(9.59)

So, to answer your question – *Why did the Devas let Bṛhaspati be their guru even though he had sex with his brothers' wives?* – it's because it was legal at one point.

Comment: Iravati Karve is not a valid source. You should edit answer with proper sources or remove those portions.

Comment: You should either update answer with new sources or remove Iravati's reference. .

Comment: Can you explain why "Iravati Karve is not a valid source"? Which site policy is this? Is Iravati Karve and all her works banned on this site? If I don't remove the reference are you going to delete the whole answer as you did [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/which-is-the-oldest-of-all-pur%c4%81%e1%b9%87as/27961?noredirect=1#comment159844_27961) or just edit and remove only the "problematic" reference? What is the site policy on how to deal with answers where some references are valid and other ref's are not valid?

Comment: This is good progress. Instead of deleting the post outright as you did [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27961), you actually edited and fixed the post.

Comment: Don't be sarcastic.

Comment: That's not sarcasm. It's genuine appreciation of the way you handled this post different from the other. Also, it's surprising to learn code of conduct from a mod who calls other's posts "half-baked knowledge" and then defends it saying "that's not offensive, it's subjective." It doesn't harm reading the [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) once in a while, with special focus on: "1. As a moderator, your actions now represent the community, so you will be held to a higher standard of behavior."

Comment: "2. Whenever possible, try to leave frequent comments on posts where you’ve taken (or considered taking) a moderator action, explaining the reasoning. This is important so that community members can learn the norms of the community and the moderation policies."

Comment: If you followed meta posts and discussions happened an year ago, then you would clearly understand which sources are off topic and on topic. Anycase, don't make sarcastic comments. Consider this as final warning. And don't just argue on every post regarding this policy of sources and Mods are not obliged to give reasons every time after one one year or convince you every time on same issue. If you don't like new policy, just move one.

Comment: "you would clearly understand which sources are off topic" - I do not, which is why I asked: "Is Iravati Karve and all her works banned on this site?" which you did not clarify. "If I don't remove the reference are you going to delete the whole answer as you did here" - you didn't answer this too. As a moderator you are required to clarify site policies and not leave users guessing which is why recommended reading the Theory of Moderation and abide by it. If you don't want to follow it, that's totally up to you. As a user I have a right to ask for clarification.

Comment: "And don't just argue on every post" - are you misrepresenting facts. This is only the second post I commented since last year. I don't understand why are these simple questions irritating you. If you don't want to answer you can walk away from the discussion instead of threatening users with warnings.

Comment: Legal at that point. Quite wrong. Dharmashastras are very authoritive maybe more authoritivy than Itihasa. And the relation between wife and brother in law is well present in Mahabharata and Ramayana as well. In MBH we have seen Kunti calling Dhritrastra father. So your assumption is very much wrong. Kindly edit your answer.